# What is $\int x! $ $ dx$?

Tags: integration

What is $\int x! $ $ dx$. $f(x)=x! $ looks something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%29%3Dx!+from+0+to+4). Do we have any formula for finding this indefinite integral.

Comment: Short answer: No. There is no formula. It does not make sense to take the integral of a discrete valued function. The Gamma Function on the other hand is a function that acts like the factorial function for all non-negative integers and also has values for a real $x$. So if you consider extending your factorial function $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$ then the indefinite integral of the Gamma function is something that can be discussed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the gamma function definition of factorial
$$x! = \int_0^\infty y^{x}e^{-y} dy$$
and change the order of integration in the resulting double integral

$$\int_b^a x!dx = \int_b^a\int_0^\infty y^{x}e^{-y} dy dx = \int_0^\infty \int_b^a y^{x}e^{-y} dx dy $$

that might lead to a solution.

Comment: $x! = \int_0^\infty y^x e^{-y} dy = \Gamma(y+1)$, you're off by one.

Comment: Can you do it without using gamma function !!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks.

Comment: @Abstraction Then it will make no sense!

Comment: You are wrong. $x! \neq \Gamma(x)$. $x! = \Gamma(x+1)$, so the first integral is wrong because of it. Furthermore the [_domains_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) are really not the same.

Comment: @Abstraction: The question you asked used the gamma function (e.g. that's what wolframalpha plotted), so no.

Comment: @user153012 I was off by one as NajibIdrissi pointed out. I corrected it. I am aware of the domains of factorial and the gamma function not being the same. But then I don't see how the factorial defined only integers can be integrated as asked by the OP.

Comment: @L'universo I think your formula is wrong also for now, because $\Gamma(x+1)$ has an $x$ in the exponent and not $x-1$.

Comment: @user153012 ok thanks

Answer (score 2):

The question is weird, because the [*factorial function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) is defined for nonnegative integers by $ n!=\prod_{k=1}^n k$ definition. That is why you rather could make a [*summation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) of it than an [*integral*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral). The integration is not a tool for discrete functions.

On the other hand as @L'universo said there is a generalization of factorial function called [*Gamma function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which is defined on the whole complex plane, so maybe you can use $\int \Gamma(t+1) dt$ this. But I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: OP WolframAlpha plots the Gamma function in your input. You want to find the integral for factorial which wouldn't work because integrals are not defined for integers. Please consider what exactly you need.